# How to add a " waiting" icon for an ajax in WP frontend?

Tags: jquery, templates, ajax

This is my search js code for processing search :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('#searchsubmit').click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();

        var searchval = $('#s').val(); // get search term

        $.post(
            WPaAjax.ajaxurl,
            {
                action : 'wpa56343_more',
                searchval : searchval
            },
            function( response ) {
                $('#results').empty();
                $('#results').append( response );
            }
        );
    });

});
```

My question is how to add an icon of waiting (the one that is used in WP admin) near the search button (#searchsubmit) so the user knows after the click that it's working? The best would be if I use only javasccript inside my existing js code I have posted here.

Comment: Just a suggestion: But you could change the css background of the search button to be the spinning ajax circle. That image is a gif and located somewhere in wp-includes/. Possibly with .addClass() or .css()

Answer (score 9):

You can use the inbuilt spinner class :

Add the class to the HTML where you want the spinner to appear, for example after your search button :

```
<button type="button" id="searchsubmit">Search Button</button>
<span class="spinner"></span> <!-- Add this spinner class where you want it to appear-->
```

In jQuery you should add the **is-active class** to the spinner immediately after the click event; then in your ajax post response you **remove the is-active class** :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#searchsubmit').click(function(e){ 

        e.preventDefault();

         $(".spinner").addClass("is-active"); // add the spinner is-active class before the Ajax posting 

        $.post(
            WPaAjax.ajaxurl,
            {
                action : 'your_action',
                data : data
            },
            function( response ) {

                 $(".spinner").removeClass("is-active"); // remove the class after the data has been posted 

            }
        );
    });

});
```

Hope that helps. [See more](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/04/23/spinners-and-dismissible-admin-notices-in-4-2/) from WordPress core docs

Comment: That spinner isn't available in the frontend, it is only injected to the admin CSS.

Answer (score 3):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#searchsubmit').click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();

        var $button = $(this);
        $button.addClass('disabled').after('<div class="load-spinner"><img src="http://domain.com/path/to/image.gif" /></div>');

        var searchval = $('#s').val(); // get search term

        $.post(
            WPaAjax.ajaxurl,
            {
                action : 'wpa56343_more',
                searchval : searchval
            },
            function( response ) {
                $('#results').empty();
                $('#results').append( response );

                $button.removeClass('disabled');
                $('.load-spinner').remove();
            }
        );
    });

});
```

Comment: Small hint. WordPress have since 4.2 a spinner inside the core, include the class `spinner`. Examples [here](https://github.com/bueltge/WordPress-Admin-Style/blob/master/patterns/spinners.php) and background [here](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/04/23/spinners-and-dismissible-admin-notices-in-4-2/).

Comment: There have been spinners in core a lot longer than that. They are very useful.

Comment: @Jake/@bueltge right, but never in the front end (not by default). Those scripts/styes only in the admin area

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('#searchsubmit').click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        var self = $( this );

        var loaderContainer = $( '<span/>', {
            'class': 'loader-image-container'
        }).insertAfter( self );

        var loader = $( '<img/>', {
            src: GET_YOUR_BASE_URL + '/wp-admin/images/loading.gif',
            'class': 'loader-image'
        }).appendTo( loaderContainer );


        var searchval = $('#s').val(); // get search term

        $.post(
            WPaAjax.ajaxurl,
            {
                action : 'wpa56343_more',
                searchval : searchval
            },
            function( response ) {
                $('#results').empty();
                $('#results').append( response );
                loaderContainer.remove();
            }
        );
    });
});
```

All you have to do now is get the beginning path of the url to wp-admin and the code should work. Hope this helps.

Comment: Small hint. WordPress have since 4.2 a spinner inside the core, include the class `spinner`. Examples [here](https://github.com/bueltge/WordPress-Admin-Style/blob/master/patterns/spinners.php) and background [here](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/04/23/spinners-and-dismissible-admin-notices-in-4-2/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function($)
{
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () 
    {
        
        //Set the Valid Flag to True if one RadioButton from the Group of RadioButtons is checked.
        var isValid = $("input[name=gender]").is(":checked");   
        //Display error message if no RadioButton is checked.
        $("#spnError")[0].style.display = isValid ? "none" : "block";
    }),

    $('#contact_form').validate(
    {
        rules:
        {
            uname:
            {
                required:true,
                minlength:3,
                maxlength:15
            },
            uemail:
            {
                required:true,
                email: true,
                minlength:3,                    
            },
            upass:
            {
                required:true,
                minlength:3,
                maxlength:15
            },
            cpass:
            {
                required:true,
                equalTo:'#inputpassword'
            },
            uaddres:
            {
                required:true,
                minlength:3,
                maxlength:100
            },
            gender:
            {
                required:true
            },
            ucity:
            {
                required:true,
                minlength:2,
                maxlength:15
            },
            ustate:
            {
                required:true
            },
            uzip:
            {
                required:true,
                minlength:6,
                maxlength:6 
            }
        
        },
        messages:
        {
            gender:
            {
                required:''
            }
        },
        submitHandler:function(form)
        {
            event.preventDefault();

            var nameid  = $("#inputname").val();
            var emailid = $("#inputemail").val();               
            var passid = $("#inputpassword").val();
            var addid = $("#inputaddress").val();
            var genderid=$('#inputgender[name="gender"]:checked').val();
            var cityid = $("#inputcity").val();
            var stateid = $("#inputstate").val();
            var zipid = $("#inputzip").val();

            var link="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>"
            var form_data=$('#contact_form');
            
            $.ajax({
                    url: link,
                    type: 'post',
                    data: 
                    {
                        action:'contact_form_data',
                        data:form_data.serialize()
                    },
                    beforeSend:function()
                    {
                            $('.loader').show();
                    },
                    success: function (response) 
                    {
                        msg="<div>"+response+"</div>";
                        $('#msg').html(msg);

                        console.log(response);
                        $("#contact_form")[0].reset();
                        $('.loader').hide();
                    }
                });

        }

    });
});
```

Comment: I guess the only relevant bit here is the `$('.loader').show();` and `$('.loader').hide();`? The rest looks like an entirely different form from the question. Where does the loader element come from?

Comment: As Rup mentioned, the relationship between the question and this code is unclear - if it is indeed an answer to the question, a few sentences describing how this code addresses the question could go a long way! There's a lot of good tips on [what goes in to a good answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in our [help]