# JS button animation for ajax the WordPress style

Tags: css, admin

I'm creating a backend ajax functionality form, and I'd like it to stay within the WordPress style.

There is a small spinning circle animation that appears on certain forms, like when you try to search for a plugin in the repo in the

How can I recreate that spinning animation?

Comment: [This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/342918/16121) points to a [spinner class in Core](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/04/23/spinners-and-dismissible-admin-notices-in-4-2/).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Paj J pointing the way. Just do this:

```
<div class = "spinner is-active"></div>
```